# How to change float of this button?

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

HiEveryone,

I'm new Javafx and trying to change the float of this button as to `Right side` from the current `Left side`.. How to do that?

I'm using simply `Pane` as a container at the moment.

Have a look into this screenshot:

[image]

How to do that? ..pls help

Thanks in advance!

**EDITED**

Source code:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start (Stage primaryStage){
        primaryStage.setTitle("Modern web browser made by Rajendra arora.");
        WebView wv = new WebView();
        wv.setLayoutX(0.0);
        wv.setLayoutY(40.0);
        wv.setPrefHeight(Double.MAX_EXPONENT);
        wv.setPrefWidth(Double.MAX_EXPONENT);
        WebEngine we = wv.getEngine();
        we.load("http://www.google.com/");

        Button btn=new Button("Go");


        TextField tf = new TextField("http://www.google.com/");
        tf.setLayoutX(1.0);
        tf.setPrefWidth(Double.MAX_EXPONENT);
        tf.setPrefHeight(25.0);

        Pane sp = new Pane();
        sp.getChildren().add(tf);
        sp.getChildren().add(btn);
        sp.getChildren().add(wv);

        Scene scene = new Scene(sp, 600, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: What layout are you using ?

Comment: I'm using simply `Pane` as a container .. pls see my code .. as i edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `HBox` to hold the textfield and button, later add it to the `Pane`

```
HBox hbox = new HBox();
hbox.getChildren().addAll(tf, btn);
Pane sp = new Pane();
sp.getChildren().add(hbox);
sp.getChildren().add(wv);
```

Comment: Okay, I can see the textfield but unable to see button .. [screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/8l7f5by23/)